# power bi data flow refresh failed Error: An internal error occurred

Tags: mysql, powerbi, google-cloud-dataflow, gateway, powerbi-datasource

I have been trying to refresh my dataflow which consists of 6 million rows and around 500 columns I am a premium user this data flow takes around 2 hours and 20 min and then gets failed error mentioned below  my data source is MySQL
Error: An internal error occurred.. RootActivityId = 01290be1-c38e-4bad-8a49-d80c0000ab75.Param1 = Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\PBIEgwService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\On-premises data gateway\Spooler\2f6805d9-bbd9-47f4-9fdc-32f67123cc48.1999' is denied. [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage]=Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\PBIEgwService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\On-premises data gateway\Spooler\2f6805d9-bbd9-47f4-9fdc-32f67123cc48.1999' is denied. [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult]=-2147024891 [InnerType]=UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\PBIEgwService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\On-premises data gateway\Spooler\2f6805d9-bbd9-47f4-9fdc-32f67123cc48.1999' is denied. [GatewayPipelineErrorCode]=DM_GWPipeline_UnknownError [ErrorShortName]=GatewayClientErrorResponseException[GatewayId=1832410]/Wrapped(UnauthorizedAccessException)[HResult=-2147024891] [ExceptionErrorShortName]=GatewayClientErrorResponseException[GatewayId=1832410] Request ID: 2687c3bc-f535-7f31-fd7c-327b08268155.

Comment: have you opened a support ticket with power bi?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.